# How to show $\mathrm{Sym}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) + \mathrm{Skew}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})= \mathrm{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\mathrm{Sym}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) + \mathrm{Skew}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) \stackrel{?}{=} \mathrm{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$$ Using the simplest core ideas of linear algebra, could someone perhaps give a hint as to where I might start to show this to be the case?

Comment: Compute the dimension of the three spaces, and the intersection betwee $Sym$ and $Skew$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez How should I think of intersections of matrices?

Comment: You should not think of intersections of matrices, for that does not make any sense! :-) I suggested that you figure out what is the intersection betwee $Sym$ and $skew$, which are *sets of matrices*, not matrices (they are actually subspaces)

Comment: Do you know the trick to show that every function is the sum of an even function and an odd one? Here it is: $f(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$. Now this should give you enough inspiration to solve your problem.

Comment: That's right, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, you can use dimension. There is a more elementary way, which generalizes exactly the same way to cases where the dimension argument fails, namely in $C^*$ and von Neumann algebras.

Here is the trick:

> $$
> M=\frac{M+M^t}{2}+\frac{M-M^t}{2}.
> $$

Recall that $(M^t)^t=M$ and that $M$ is symmetric (resp. antisymmetric) if and only if $M^t=M$ (resp. $M^t=-M$).
I let you check it proves the harder direction of the equality you want, namely $M_n(\mathbb{R})\subseteq Sym+Skew$. The reverse inclusion is obvious.

Comment: Oh, wow! That's what I just wrote essentially...

Comment: What do you mean by "I['ll] let you check it proves the only nontrivial direction of the equality you want."

Comment: It means that ${\rm Sym}+{\rm Skew}\subseteq M_n$ is trivial but the inclusion of subspaces in the other direction, namely $M_n\subseteq {\rm Sym}+{\rm Skew}$, is comparatively not trivial.

Comment: @Trancot THe idea is here in what you wrote, as the last formula is the same as what I wrote. But everything you say before the formula does not prove anything. You say if $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$...the whole point is to start from an arbitrary matrix. So you can't make this assumption.

Comment: @Trancot I have added a few words to be more explicit on what you have to prove from there.

Comment: The exact same argument works whenever you have group of order two acting linearly on a vector space of characteristic $\neq2$. Isn't representation theory wonderful! Next step: what about a symmetry of order three? (hint: This time you need cubic roots of 1 instead of square roots of 1)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes. As you can see in my comment above, I was that close to do it for an arbitrary involution...But I had never thought of a cubic generalization, thanks!

Comment: @julien See my most recent edit to my answer. Is this better?

Comment: @julien "The reverse inclusion" is your trick, yes?

Comment: @Trancot THe reverse inclusion does not require any trick. ANy sum of two subspaces is a subspace of $M_n$. I have to go, sorry. Good luck. I'll see tomorrow if you still have questions. One last thing, since $(M+M^t)^t=M^t+M=M+M^t$, the lhs in the formula is a symmetric matrix. Continue from here!

Comment: @julien Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here I give another proof:

We can see easily that

$$f:\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\to \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R}),\quad A\mapsto A^T$$
is an endomorphism of vector spaces and that $f^2=\mathrm{Id}$ so $x^2-1$ is the minimal polynomial of $f$, moreover we have $\ker(f-\mathrm{Id})=\mathrm{Sym}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\ker(f+\mathrm{Id})=\mathrm{Skew}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ hence
$$\ker(f-\mathrm{Id})\oplus\ker(f+\mathrm{Id})=\mathrm{Sym}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\oplus \mathrm{Skew}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})=\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$$

Comment: @Trancot You can see another answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If $M_1 \in Sym_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, then $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$, so $a_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}a_{ij}+\frac{1}{2}a_{ji}$. Similarly, if $M_2 \in Skew_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, then $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$, so $a_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}a_{ij}-\frac{1}{2}a_{ji}$, by the definition of symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices; thus, $\frac{1}{2}a_{ij}+\frac{1}{2}a_{ji}+\frac{1}{2}a_{ij}-\frac{1}{2}a_{ji}=a_{ij}$.

---

I think there is a clearer way...

Comment: What your first sentences prove is essentially: $Sym\subseteq \frac{1}{2}(Sym+Sym)$ and $Skew\subseteq \frac{1}{2}(Skew+Skew)$. But it does not prove much more. And certainly not the deisred result. Your last formula, on the other hand is correct (that's the coordinate version of the formula I gave). But you need to understand it holds for any matrix. Then you need to check the lhs defines a symmetric matrix, while the rhs yields a skew symmetric matrix. It is nicer to do it with the transpose $M^t$.